# Can't get a button to appear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i cant seem to get a button to show up in my game window. Can someone please explain to me why this is? is it only appearing for one frame then going away really fast before i can see it? or is it just not coming up at all?

my state manager.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.States;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
private IStateBase activeState;

void Start()
{
    activeState = new BeginState(this);

}

void Update()
{
    if (activeState != null)
                    activeState.StateUpdate ();
}
void OnGUI()
{ 
    if (activeState != null)
                    activeState.ShowIt ();

    }


public void SwitchState(IStateBase newState)
{
    activeState = newState;

}
}
```

My First state.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

namespace Assets.Code.States
{
public class BeginState:IStateBase 
{
    private StateManager manager;

    public BeginState(StateManager managerRef)   //Constructor
    {
        manager = managerRef;
        Debug.Log ("Constructing BeginState");
    }
    public void StateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
                            manager.SwitchState (new PlayState (manager));
                    }
            }
    public void ShowIt()
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 150, 100), "Press to play")) 
        {
            manager.SwitchState(new PlayState (manager));
                    }

            }

}
}
```

Comment: i figured it out myself! the Update had to be written as UpDate lol. thanks anyways to anyone who may have stopped to look to try and help! :)

Comment: Please add your solution and mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
attach this script to camera:

```
public class Examplebutton : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnGUI() {

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Click"))
        Debug.Log("Clicked");

    }
}
```

Gui must be attached to camera with Guilayer and must be in void OnGUI()

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the Statemanager.cs script to the camera in your scene.  I hit the same problem and this was the solution for me.